# How to show number counts on terminal in linux

Tags: linux, awk

Please how can I count the list of numbers in a file

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i>=0 && $i<=25){print $i}}}'
```

Using the command above I can display the range of numbers on the terminal but if there are so many it will be difficult to count them.  Please how can I show the count of the numbers on the terminal for example

```
1-20, 
2-22, 
3-23, 
4-24,
etc
```

I know I can use `wc` but I don't know how to infuse it into the command above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the output to `sort -n` and `uniq -c`

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i>=0 && $i<=25){print $i}}}' filename | sort -n | uniq -c
```

You need to sort first because `uniq` requires all the same elements to be consecutive.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (0<=$i && $i<=25) cnts[$i]++ }
    END { for (n in cnts) print n, cnts[n] }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm personally an awk fan, you might be glad to learn about `grep -o` functionality.  I'm using `grep -o` to match all numbers in the file, and then awk can be used to pick all the numbers between 0 and 25 (inclusive).  Last, we can use sort and uniq to count the results.

```
grep -o  "[0-9][0-9]*" file  |  awk ' $1 >= 0 && $1 <= 25 ' |  sort -n  | uniq -c
```

Of course, you could do the counting in awk with an associative array as Ed Morton suggests:

```
egrep -o  "\d+" file |  awk ' $1 >= 0 && $1 <= 25 ' |  awk '{cnt[$1]++} END { for (i in cnt) printf("%s-%s\n",  i,cnt[i] ) } '
```

I modified Ed's code (typically not a good idea - I've been reading his code for years now) to show a modular approach - an awk script for filtering numbers in the range of 0 and 25 and another awk script for counting a list (of anything).

I also provided another subtle difference from my first script with egrep instead of grep.

To be honest, the second awk script generates some unexpected output, but I wanted to share an example of a more general approach.  EDIT:  I applied Ed's suggestion to correct the unexpected output - it's fine now.